# ROS Installation on Red Hat: No rule to make target 'lib64/lib64/libboost_thread-mt

Tags: boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Collapse all
Expand all
Print all
In new window
ROS Installation on Red Hat: No rule to make target 'lib64/lib64/libboost_thread-mt"
Yeon Grace Lee

2:24 PM (1 hour ago)

to ros-users
Hi everyone,

I am in the process of installing ROS (from Willow Garage) on my
machine which currently runs Red Hat Release 6.2 (Santiago). When I
run "make" inside root/build directory of Ros, I get an error that
says "No rule to make target
'usr/lib64/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5'. It's funny that it is
looking for libboost in lib64/lib64, instead of just in the lib64
directory. Does anyone have any thoughts  on where the path to
libboost is set incorrectly?

Thanks,

Grace Lee

"Terminal output"
Scanning dependencies of target rospack
[ 10%] Building CXX object rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack_backcompat.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/utils.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack_cmdline.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/tinyxml-2.5.3/tinyxml.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/tinyxml-2.5.3/tinyxmlparser.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/tinyxml-2.5.3/tinyxmlerror.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/librospack.so
[ 11%] Built target rospack
Scanning dependencies of target rospackexe
[ 11%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rospackexe.dir/src/rospack_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/rospack
[ 11%] Built target rospackexe
Scanning dependencies of target rosstackexe
[ 11%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rosstackexe.dir/src/rosstack_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/rosstack
[ 11%] Built target rosstackexe
Scanning dependencies of target roslib
[ 11%] Building CXX object
ros/core/roslib/CMakeFiles/roslib.dir/src/package.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target
`/usr/lib64/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5', needed by` lib/libroslib.so'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [ros/core/roslib/CMakeFiles/roslib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Reply

Forward

Yeon Grace Lee

2:29 PM (1 hour ago)

to ros-users
Hi everyone,

I am in the process of installing ROS (from Willow Garage) on my
machine which currently runs Red Hat Release 6.2 (Santiago). When I
run "make" inside root/build directory of Ros, I get an error that
says "No rule to make target
'usr/lib64/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5'. It's funny that it is
looking for libboost in lib64/lib64, instead of just in the lib64
directory. Does anyone have any thoughts  on where the path to
libboost is set incorrectly?

Thanks,

Grace Lee

"Terminal output"
Scanning dependencies of target rospack
[ 10%] Building CXX object rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack_backcompat.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/utils.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/src/rospack_cmdline.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/tinyxml-2.5.3/tinyxml.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/tinyxml-2.5.3/tinyxmlparser.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rospack.dir/tinyxml-2.5.3/tinyxmlerror.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/librospack.so
[ 11%] Built target rospack
Scanning dependencies of target rospackexe
[ 11%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rospackexe.dir/src/rospack_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/rospack
[ 11%] Built target rospackexe
Scanning dependencies of target rosstackexe
[ 11%] Building CXX object
rospack/CMakeFiles/rosstackexe.dir/src/rosstack_main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../bin/rosstack
[ 11%] Built target rosstackexe
Scanning dependencies of target roslib
[ 11%] Building CXX object
ros/core/roslib/CMakeFiles/roslib.dir/src/package.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target
`/usr/lib64/lib64/libboost_thread-mt.so.5', needed by` lib/libroslib.so'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [ros/core/roslib/CMakeFiles/roslib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Reply

Forward

Click here to Reply or Forward
Rackspace Cloud
Ads – Why this ad?
Cloud Hosting for Websites, Servers and Storage. Sign up Today!
[www.Rackspace.com/Cloud](http://www.Rackspace.com/Cloud)
512
36% full
Using 3,742 MB of your 10,265 MB
©2012 Google - Terms & Privacy
Last account activity: 9 minutes ago
Details

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38044/ros-installation-on-red-hat:-no-rule-to-make-target-%27lib64/lib64/libboost_thread-mt/) by [yglee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2776/yglee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set the boost location with the [$ROS_BOOST_PATH](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_BOOST_ROOT) environment variable.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1